# how to prevent content jumping while images are loading?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 4 col layout with image thumbnails.

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset='utf-8'>
      <title>KTM Cart</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class='container-fluid'>
         <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/71"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/71/PCR15_10D23X_ENVIRO_SQ.jpg" alt="Pcr15 10d23x enviro sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Sign
                        -
                        $23.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="NY3tjz7PeQ3QNlBvMx0qY0aF8UjYG7ve3BpPYesneuqxV0eLJGMiIp3pxuMjc0MbQ8jE1apFtKtagCSdodM39g==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="71" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/72"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/72/PCR15_15P317X_ENVIRO_SQ__1_.jpg" alt="Pcr15 15p317x enviro sq  1 " />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Post
                        -
                        $32.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="fccnLj9VBQfZx8PfGNNcCJuDgvoUBJFrjnTKpF5TIPz5HY0qJfleKJQYVVMIvTVwns63Z2Zanh4I7qFYFKdt4A==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="72" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/73"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/73/PCR17_12SP155_16x16_ENVIRO_V2_SQ.jpg" alt="Pcr17 12sp155 16x16 enviro v2 sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Frame
                        -
                        $43.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="jhyuuFWo7Ay/km9/FhdRnvVp6HKq1EwTQ/a40sg9CkUKxgS8TwS3I/JN+fMGeTjm8CTd79iKQ2bFbNMugslHWQ==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="73" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/74"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/74/RED15_15REH36_WDR_SILVER_SQ.jpg" alt="Red15 15reh36 wdr silver sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Plate
                        -
                        $32.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="E+vS9UnB6VsNwURH3YQBIPj2Ujekj6Ll5Y3ahD4+RjyXMXjxU22ydEAe0svN6mhY/btnqtbRrZBjF7F4dMoLIA==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="74" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/76"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/76/RED17_18RES6_ENVIRO_SQ.jpg" alt="Red17 18res6 enviro sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Charger
                        -
                        $421.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="02gSs0Ih218t2v6+fbhy4Ro7a9qf9jczFRQuRHaL7gVXsri3WI2AcGAFaDJt1huZH3ZeR+2oOEaTjkW4PH+jGQ==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="76" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/77"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/77/RED17_18RES20X_ENVIRO_LIT_SQ.jpg" alt="Red17 18res20x enviro lit sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Wooden Frame
                        -
                        $43.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="29myoPci0jCZ7AmNtemmXumHlfscEdwO6BDJfsHVXwtfAxik7Y6JH9QznwGlh88m7MqgZm5P03tuiqKCiyESFw==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="77" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/78"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/78/RED17_18RES26_WDR_SQ.jpg" alt="Red17 18res26 wdr sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Watches
                        -
                        $32.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="BlC0nEu9+nnmpjU56U1QFMk8feLIvJ0x+QbjqKMOb2iCih6YURGhVqt5o7X5IzlszHFIf7rikkR/nIhU6foidA==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="78" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/79"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/79/RED18_18REF12X_ENVIRO_SQ.jpg" alt="Red18 18ref12x enviro sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Dolls
                        -
                        $41.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="lM7G6iXd8+qRbvu3YrZiUppGg+22oNU23ApR70of21IQFGzuP3GoxdyxbTty2Asqnwu2cMT+2kNakDoTAOuWTg==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="79" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/80"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/80/RED18_18REF14_ENVIRO_SQ.jpg" alt="Red18 18ref14 enviro sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Wall Clock
                        -
                        $51.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="4HrP8Oy/ohuS+3aoUoEyhQ1OZxlwkmhfTHt5xfY+qu1koGX09hP5NN8k4CRC71v9CANShALMZyrK4RI5vMrn8Q==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="80" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/81"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/81/RED18_18REH21BK_WDR_SQ.jpg" alt="Red18 18reh21bk wdr sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Deer
                        -
                        $71.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="+xGtt0hzVHiOaZO/2bJmzBIuWpxRZUH0TtkRam9TMal/ywezUt8PV8O2BTPJ3A+0F2NvASM7ToHIQ3qWJad8tQ==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="81" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/82"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/82/RED18_18REH28TN_WDR_EDITED_SQ.jpg" alt="Red18 18reh28tn wdr edited sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Book
                        -
                        $51.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="bsrtFfe0Qz5OcnE8ZKIu0V58Z54xSLr89a8s8Z8lQoXqEEcR7RgYEQOt57B0zEepWzFSA0MWtYlzNUcN1dEPmQ==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="82" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/83"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/83/RED18_18RES70_WDR_SQ.jpg" alt="Red18 18res70 wdr sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Bangle
                        -
                        $41.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="/luaLmb53A1PrNTUKYBwC36ZgGWPkceXXOWd4FxYMX56gTAqfFWHIgJzQlg57hlze9S1+P3PyOLaf/YcFqx8Yg==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="83" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/84"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/84/RED18_18RES71X_WDR_SQ.jpg" alt="Red18 18res71x wdr sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Money Clip
                        -
                        $42.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="6tkipTfY6E8J5J0AWPuICdX9wOwp2pe+/N+pKfXRNh9uA4ihLXSzYEQ7C4xIleFx0LD1cVuEmMt6RcLVvyV7Aw==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="84" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/85"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/85/RED17_18RES8X_WDR_SQ.jpg" alt="Red17 18res8x wdr sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Pedant
                        -
                        $24.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="/WbnWYDbDavvgW5bxM/RcKFPNoh1Om7Y9ETdIS44Lpd5vE1dmndWhKJe+NfUobgIpAIDFQdkYa1y3rbdZMxjiw==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="85" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/86"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/86/elephant.jpg" alt="Elephant" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Elephant
                        -
                        $27.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="/bcemiDzSUWhH8msacsk84mBWa/Y9ADp4T84grk4Lfp5bbSeOl8SauzAXyB5pU2LjMxsMqqqD5xnpVN+88xg5g==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="86" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-6 mb-4'>
               <div class='card'>
                  <div>
                     <a href="/public/75"><img width="300px" height="200px" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/uploads/product/photo/75/RED16_16RES16M_WDR_CP_SQ.jpg" alt="Red16 16res16m wdr cp sq" />
                     </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class='card-body'>
                     <p class='card-text'>
                        Bag
                        -
                        $141.00
                     </p>
                     <form class="new_order_item" id="new_order_item" action="/order_items" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="//9cCdQi7iPgN+lOu+z///giGwUkZXwUDeoayXGTXu97JfYNzo61DK3of8KrgpaH/W8umFY7c2GLcHE1O2cT8w==" />
                        <div class='input-group'>
                           <input value="1" class="form-control" type="hidden" name="order_item[quantity]" id="order_item_quantity" />
                           <div class='input-group-btn'>
                              <input value="75" type="hidden" name="order_item[product_id]" id="order_item_product_id" />
                              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add to Cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-disable-with="Add to Cart" />
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

The problem is when the page is loading the image section is initially collapsed and when image loading is complete the image appears. This gives jumping effect. How can i show empty box of fixed size before the image finishes downloading and show it. This will prevent content jumping. I even tried by wrapping image in div tag with fixed height and width and it doesn't seem to work. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

For an example please look at the layout of http://www.bbc.com/

There images appear in the box of fixed dimension so content jumping is prevented.

Comment: see here:https://css-tricks.com/content-jumping-avoid/

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the image inside the div and set a height to the image. So until the image loads, CSS will render the height which will keep the layout intact.

Comment: i have wrapped image in div block <div style='width:300; height:200;'> .

Comment: So the height is equal to 200 bananas? Or 200 inches maybe? I'm confused, aren't you?

Comment: you have to add unit for width and height like 'px'

Comment: ok i have tried setting px and yet there is still jumping effect. please look at the updated code above. sorry i donot have lot of experience with frontend so i am asking help from frontend experts. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The method you used by wrapping `<img>` with `<div>` with fixed height is correct. But there may be some issues related to float that make the issue still exist. Try applying `float:left` or `overflow:hidden` for the wrapping `<div>` with height applied.

Answer (score -1):

ok this trick worked for me where the img wrapping div has class item.

```
.img-thumbnail {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.item {
    min-height: 300px;
    max-height: auto;
    float: left;

}
```